# Precalculus equation solving with inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

For which a $\in \mathbb{R}$ does the equation

$$|x-1| + 2|x-2| = a$$

have two solutions?

I divided this into three cases:

**Case 1**

$x \geq 2$:

$$x-1 +2(x-2) = a$$
$$x-1+2x-4 = a$$
$$3x-5 = a$$
$$x = \frac{a +5}{3}$$

This has a solution if $a \geq 1$ to match the requirement $x \geq 2$.

**Case 2**

$1 < x < 2$:

$$-2 (x-2)+x-1 = a$$
$$-x+3 = a$$
$$x = -a + 3$$

This has a solution if $1 < a < 2$.

**Case 3**

$x \leq 1$

$$-2(x-2)-x+1 = a$$
$$-2x+4-x+1 = a$$
$$-3x+5 = a$$
$$x = \frac{a-5}{-3}$$

This has a solution if $a \geq 2$.

However, I do not quite understand how to make a judgement about what values for a this equation has two solutions, since there are no square terms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have seen that if $a\geq 1$ then this has a solution $x_0$ where $x_0\geq 2$, and you have also seen that if $a\geq 2$, then this has a solution $x_1 \leq 1$. Combining these two, you can conclude that if $a\geq 2$ then your equation has two solutions, one less than or equal to $1$ and one greater than or equal to $2$.

$\textbf{Note}:$ For better understanding I suggest you draw the graph of $|x+1|+2|x-2|$.

Comment: What about in the region 1 < a <2? Does that not have two solutions for a, one from case 1 and one from case 2?

Comment: Yes absolutely!!! I missed on that...but yes that is the case, so, your final answer will be $a\geq 1$. Actually the graph will be V shape with the bottom point being $(2,1)$.